# will_paginate not working on all views

Tags: ruby-on-rails, indexing, will-paginate

I am following the rails tutorial and using the will_paginate gem. 
I have a posts index and a users index, but the gem only works in the posts index. Here is my code:

users_controller.rb

```
    def index
      @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20) 
    end
```

index.html.erb

```
<div class="listed">
    <p>Users Directory</p>
    <%= will_paginate %>
        <ul>
            <%= render @users %>
        </ul> 
    <%= will_paginate %>
</div>
```

_user.html.erb

```
 <li>
<%= link_to user.name, user %> 
            <% if current_user.admin? && !current_user?(user) %>
            <%= link_to("delete", user, method: "delete", data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"}, class: "small-button") %>
            <% end %>
</li>
```

I have the exact same syntax for the posts' view and controller so I don't know what I'm doing wrong with the users'...
Let me know if I need to add more code.

Thanks.

Comment: I think you missed object which should be paginated `<%= will_paginate @users %>`

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [will_paginate github repo](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate). It clearly states that to render your users you need to do:

```
## perform a paginated query:
@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])

# or, use an explicit "per page" limit:
Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 30)

## render page links in the view:
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
```

So your index.htm.erb will be

```
<div class="listed">
  <p>Users Directory</p>
  <%= will_paginate @users %>
</div>
```

Comment: that just doesn't show anything at all, but I added the users variable to will_paginate and it works now. thanks!

Comment: @user3417583 what do you mean by doesn't show anything?

Comment: Did you set your users in controller with @users= User.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20)

Comment: Yeah, that notation wasn't the problem. It works now, though. Thanks for the help!